# App communication using intents with multiples activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm currently doing a communication between two apps using intents. The first app launch a intent captured by the second app. In this second app, I have a process with multiples activities and at the end of the process, the last activity should return the result to the caller app. In a simple diagram is something like this:

```
App 1 ----- Launch Intent -----> App 2 Activity1
                                 App 2 Activity2
                                 App 2 Activity3
App1 <----- Intent Response ---- App 2 Activity4
OnActivityResult
```

I suppose that in this case, the App2 Activity1 should be the activity in charge to respond to App1, for this reason I have tried to "empty the back stack" from App2 Activity 4 using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` but I'm not able to "kill" the App2 from the App2 Activity1, , It always come back to App2 Activity3.

I have thought that another alternative could be start each activity on App2 always waiting for result and from App2 Activity 4 init a notification chain from Activity 4 to Activity 1 but I feel that this option could have some strange behaviors if the user start to go ahead and back through the activities... :s

Any idea to achieve to send back information to app1 from app2?

Thanks.

Comment: startActivityForResult should works... but, you can use SharedPreference to storage data and move all around the app.

Comment: Hi, I'm already using the startActivityForResult from App1 to App2. Can you explain your idea about the SharePreferences?

Comment: Well, here is a good example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm or you can use my "easy" version with just one line of code: https://github.com/mkiisoft/KeySaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found a solution for the problem, as simple as, relaunch the App2 Activity1 using the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and returning back the process result included as extra in the intent.

Finally in order to return information to app1, from App2 Activity1 if the intent includes the result information, simply set the intent result and finish it.

Answer (score 0):

What about a BroadcastReceiver on App1 that would listen for result, when result is issued, it will startup App1.Activity?  Sounds good? that way, no matter how long you take in App2, you will still get back to app1?  The only downside is that it will not keep App1.Activity one on stack, but this might not matter if the data is in the broadcasted intent is what you really need. I cannot comment with number of points, but in your solution would it CLEAR_TOP also clear the activity of the original calling app? Also you could consider just using fragments vs. activities for the wizard.